# Month Interval Postgres

Tags: postgresql, intervals

What am i missing?

So basically project_status on one column and duration on the next

I have tried the following below with error -

```
SELECT
project_status
,extract(month from max(closed_date)-max(open_date)) as duration
FROM
    "analytics"."projects"
where projects_status = 'closed' 
limit 500
```

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: If you are expecting that to show the number of months between the two dates it won't for two reasons: 1) `extract(month ..)` will just return the month of a date. 2) Subtracting dates will get you integer number of days. You need to be more explicit about what you want to achieve?